# AWS ELB unhealthy 4xx

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am using express.js and graphql for backend server which uses port 4000. I am trying to connect my server with ELB but the status returns unhealthy with error code 400 or 404. These are my settings about ELB.

- Target group

[image: target group]

- Target groups registered targets

[image: target groups registered targets]

- Target groups health checks

[image: target group health checks]

If I change the path to `/graphql` it returns 400, and just `/` returns 404. It is still working with no error when I call the API but it seems like I should fix it. Could anyone please tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to handle this case is to define the path in your express application for example `/health` or `/ping` which should return HTTP status code `200`.

If `/graphql` does not return HTTP status code `200` the LB will mark the target unhealthy.

you have two option

- Update Success codes to `400`, the LB will mark the target healhty
- Define path like `/` or `/health` and return status code `200`.

In express for example

```
app.get('/health',function(req,res){
res.status(200).send("instance is healthy");
})
```

Then setting for LB will 
[image]

Or if you want to go without changing in the application the below will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apollo supports a simple health check by default at this URL /.well-known/apollo/server-health ([source](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/monitoring/health-checks/)), so you can add change the path in the target group from / to the URL